# How to export and import environment variables in windows?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, windows-xp

I found it is hard to keep my environment variables sync on different machines. I just want to export the settings from one computer and import to other ones.

I think it should be possible, but don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can use RegEdit to export the following two keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

The first set are system/global environment variables; the second set are user-level variables.  Edit as needed and then import the .reg files on the new machine.

Comment: run the program regedit, highlight the keys in question and then use the "file -> export" option so save it as a file

Comment: the import is done simply with double clicking the .reg file while having admin permissions.

Comment: NOTE: This doesn't get all Environment Variables(EV)! I just did a command set path and messed up all my EV. I went to this registry and only the original EV were there. I did a system restore and got all my missing EV back to the PATH var. This registry only holds a few necessary EV, but not any of your program's EV nor any paths you set manually. BEWARE! On a command line: echo path > mybackup.txt or set > mybackup.txt for the whole backup on ALL vars/paths and ALL sys vars/paths.

Comment: @ejbytes This does copy your global variables that you set but it is probably better to export them with the CLI instead of through the registry.

Answer (score 147):

I would use the SET command from the command prompt to export all the variables, rather than just PATH as recommended above.

```
C:\> SET >> allvariables.txt
```

To import the variablies, one can use a simple loop:

```
C:\> for /F %A in (allvariables.txt) do SET %A
```

Comment: How do you import back all the exported Env. Vars. from allvariables.txt

Comment: Very nice. I just lost all my path vars doing a bad path set and had to do a system restore. Luckily I had a recent update as of today earlier. I just did a backup with this command. Nice. That registry solution only holds the original vars, but nothing that "you" (as a programmer say for new builds) created or any new install created.

Comment: On Windows 7 64-bit, if there are two identically named variables at the User level and the System level, this command gives precedence to the User level variable and omits the System level one.  This behavior makes sense, but figured it might be worth a mention in case anyone was expecting the full set from each variable type.

Comment: this command did work: `set > "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\envir variable.txt"`

Comment: Thanks @JinSnow this worked for me. The command by Kushal gave me an "access denied" error.

Comment: To answer Ash, you can use a simple for loop in the cmd prompt to import back all the variables: `for /F %A in (allvariables.txt) do SET %A`

Comment: This appears to fail when importing paths containing spaces, such as "Program Files".

Comment: In Windows 10, when importing, I believe most users will want to use `SETX` rather than `SET` – to make the change permanent. (Not having to import every time a new command window is opened.)

Comment: @Henke is correct.  Use SETX if you want it to persist.  Also, warning that this approach will mash both User and System env variables into a single file on read which it will load from and save that mixed file into the User env variables.  If that is not desirable then manually extract System env variables from that mixed file into a separate file and use the /M flag with those to import them as System env variables.

Answer (score 22):

To export user variables, open a command prompt and use regedit with /e

Example :

```
regedit /e "%userprofile%\Desktop\my_user_env_variables.reg" "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment"
```

Answer (score 16):

Combine [@vincsilver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10597721/5411817) and [@jdigital](https://stackoverflow.com/a/559841/5411817)'s answers with some modifications,

1. export `.reg` to current directory
2. add date mark

code:

```
set TODAY=%DATE:~0,4%-%DATE:~5,2%-%DATE:~8,2%

regedit /e "%CD%\user_env_variables[%TODAY%].reg" "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment"
regedit /e "%CD%\global_env_variables[%TODAY%].reg" "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
```

Output would like:

```
global_env_variables[2017-02-14].reg
user_env_variables[2017-02-14].reg
```

Comment: the **TODAY** variable depends on **%DATE%** which is dependent on how Windows Locale preferences. The above command does not work for India.  This works --> _set TODAY=%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~10,4%_

Answer (score 7):

You can get access to the environment variables in either the command line or in the registry.

**Command Line**

If you want a specific environment variable, then just type the name of it (e.g. `PATH`), followed by a `>`, and the filename to write to. The following will dump the PATH environment variable to a file named path.txt.

```
C:\> PATH > path.txt
```

**Registry Method**

The Windows Registry holds all the environment variables, in different places depending on which set you are after. You can use the registry Import/Export commands to shift them into the other PC.

*For System Variables:*

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

*For User Variables:*

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

Comment: On my machine, PATH > (or PATH >>) returned an empty text file, while SET >> worked. Windows 7 x64 bits.

Comment: Worked for me on Win7x64. Not sure what the requirements are.

Comment: From which folder do you execute this command? Mine said could not find path.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my PowerShell method

```
gci env:* | sort-object name | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "MyApp*"} | Foreach {"[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('$($_.Name)', '$($_.Value)', 'Machine')"}
```

What it does

1. Scoops up all environment variables
2. Filters them
3. Emits the formatted PowerShell needed to recreate them on another machine (assumes all are set at machine level)

So after running this on the source machine, simply transfer output onto the target machine and execute (elevated prompt if setting at machine level)

Answer (score 5):

My favorite method for doing this is to write it out as a batch script to combine both user variables and system variables into a single backup file like so, create an `environment-backup.bat` file and put in it:

```
@echo off
:: RegEdit can only export into a single file at a time, so create two temporary files.
regedit /e "%CD%\environment-backup1.reg" "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment"
regedit /e "%CD%\environment-backup2.reg" "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"

:: Concatenate into a single file and remove temporary files.
type "%CD%\environment-backup1.reg" "%CD%\environment-backup2.reg" > environment-backup.reg
del "%CD%\environment-backup1.reg"
del "%CD%\environment-backup2.reg"
```

This creates `environment-backup.reg` which you can use to re-import existing environment variables. This will *add & override* new variables, but *not* delete existing ones :)

Answer (score 1):

A PowerShell script based on @Mithrl's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42227022/8608146)

```bsh
# export_env.ps1
$Date = Get-Date
$DateStr = '{0:dd-MM-yyyy}' -f $Date

mkdir -Force $PWD\env_exports | Out-Null

regedit /e "$PWD\env_exports\user_env_variables[$DateStr].reg" "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment"
regedit /e "$PWD\env_exports\global_env_variables[$DateStr].reg" "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not being satisfied with answers from 12 years ago I've approached this a little differently.  This approach could work with Win OS flavors older than Win 8 by using `SET` instead of `SETX` which is when `SETX` began being used.

> NOTE:
> Be sure to tune the RegEx for your preferred editor to achieve desired
> results.  For RegEx specific questions please seek help from various
> sources including [tutorials available from here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).  I'm using Sublime Text 4 for search and replace RegEx examples.

> WARNING:
> I would like to point out that following this process
> blindly with copy and paste will most likely clobber existing settings
> with the source data extracted.  It DOES NOT merge the two sets of
> data.  That is your responsibility and I take no responsibility for
> any damage that may result.  Additionally, you should take time to
> remove settings from the extracted env variables that pose issues or
> no value such as changed paths and different hardware metrics such as
> CPU core counts.

This approach avoids mixing System env variables with User env variables which a handful of previous answers are plagued with.

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment">>SystemEnvVariablesSourceMachine.txt
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment">>UserEnvVariablesSourceMachine.txt
```

Clean up the files that were just created!  Import success depends on this!
Use a RegEx capable editor and use the following search and replace:

> NOTE: Some RegEx engines/tools require use of the $ character to
> represent backreference in the Replace Pattern.  If your not getting
> the expected results in search and replace give that a try.

Search Pattern:

```
(?:\A\r?\n|^HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Environment\r?\n?|^HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment\r?\n?|^\r?\n$|\r?\n\Z)
```

Replace Pattern (Literally Empty):

```
Literally Empty
```

and then

Search Pattern:

```
^\s+(.*?)\s{4}\w+\s{4}(.*?)$
```

Replace Pattern:

```
\1=\2
```

Its strongly advised you take a moment to do the same steps above on the destination machine using these file names:

```
SystemEnvVariablesDestinationMachine.txt
UserEnvVariablesDestinationMachine.txt
```

This also will serve as a backup for the upcoming import.

Once the DestinationMachine versions of the files are cleaned up its time to make a copy.  Copy of each of the DestinationMachine files and name them something like:

```
SystemEnvVariablesFinalMerge.txt
UserEnvVariablesFinalMerge.txt
```

We're not done yet, that's just a version of the file you can feel safe to edit.  Leave the DestinationMachine version of the files alone.  Consider them a backup.

Next we will merge the SourceMachine files into the FinalMerge files.  This provides a means to
manual review for cleanup of duplicates and bad data followed by a final output.  There are plenty of ways
to do this, but the easiest way I've used is to prepare the data for comparison, then compare and merge, and then reassemble the data back
so that its importable.

Apply this search and replace RegEx pattern to each Source and FinalMerge file:

Search Pattern:

```
(^\w+=|.*?(?:;|$))
```

Replace Pattern:

```
\1\n
```

Then compare each Source to FinalMerge using a diff tool such as Beyond Compare 4, Meld, or Winmerge.  My personal favorite is Beyond Compare 4.  Keep in mind the data at this time may not be sorted
so you can take care at this time to sort the data taking care not to mix up variables from key to value structure.  How to use those tools is out of scope here.  Delete env variables that you do not wish to import at this time from the FinalMerge version of the file.

Once you're satisifed with the merge with cleanup applied save the changes in the FinalMerge files then restore the key to value mapping with the following RegEx pattern:

Search Pattern:

```
(.)$\r?\n
```

Replace Pattern:

```
\1
```

Then on the destination machine import the variables with powershell:

```
Get-Content .\UserEnvVariablesFinalMerge.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $envVarDataSplit = $($_).split("=")
    if($($envVarDataSplit).count -gt 0)
    {
        Write-Output "Key: $($envVarDataSplit[0]) ~ Value: $($envVarDataSplit[1])"
        SETX $envVarDataSplit[0] "$($envVarDataSplit[1])"
    }
}
```

> NOTE:
> Run powershell as administrator for this to succeed or you will
> get an error.

```
Get-Content .\SystemEnvVariablesFinalMerge.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $envVarDataSplit = $($_).split("=")
    if($($envVarDataSplit).count -gt 0)
    {
        Write-Output "Key: $($envVarDataSplit[0]) ~ Value: $($envVarDataSplit[1])"
        SETX $envVarDataSplit[0] "$($envVarDataSplit[1])" /M
    }
}
```

> NOTE:
> If you encounter an error here its likely due to a need to
> escape a character.  You'll need to either manually enter that env
> variable or figure out the proper escaped character sequence to get
> around it.

If things have gone horribly wrong you should be able to revert to your DestinationMachine versions of the env variables using the previous command with the backup.