# Python creating a module

Tags: python, module, coding-style

I have a quick question with regards to making a module out of a python script.

Let's say I want to call my module: testingA

Currently my directory structure is like so:

- app
- config.py
- run.py

**Question**

1. Can I still make a module called testingA with that directory
   structure, or would I have to rename the "app" directory to
   "testingA"
2. Is it pythonic to have the main application folder match the module
   name?

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a directory lets call it `d`. and it looks like this:

```
d/app/
d/config.py
d/run.py
```

And you want to add a new script called `testingA.py` so that it will be:

```
d/app/
d/config.py
d/run.py
d/testingA.py
```

That would be fine.

You do not need to rename `d` to anything. And if you want to import `testingA.py` as a module from `run.py` for instance, you would just do:

```
import testingA
```

Or you could do:

```
from testingA import *
```

---

If you want to put `testingA.py` into `d/app/` however, like so:

```
d/app/testingA.py
d/config.py
d/run.py
```

Then you will need to do something like this in `run.py`:

```
import app.testingA
```

Or:

```
from app import testingA
```

Comment: What about if I wanted my testingA module to be the entire contents of /app? Would I need to make /app/ into /testingA/?

Comment: I don't think you understand what a  "module" means. Try reading [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383014/cant-import-my-own-modules-in-python), and [this](http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/making-modules.html)

Comment: Damn, I think I meant "source distribution"

Comment: Using your new found knowledge, [ask another question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: In this case the answer is yes. You have to rename `app` to `testingA`.

Comment: @Torsten I think you mean he has to rename `d` to `testingA` since `app` is inside the directory already where he wants his distribution to be.

Comment: If `d` is the project directory (but not a package itself) and he wants to do `from testingA import whatever` then no, I meant the `app` directory. `testingA` wouldn't be a python module of course, but a python package instead.