# using __import__() function in my function in python

Tags: python, import

thank you all, this problem was solved

but I don't know What is the different between them

wrong script :

```
def func(module) :
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(module['path'])
    tmp = __import__(module['name'])
    os.chdir(cwd)
```

working well script :

```
def func(module) :
    sys.path.append(module['path'])
    tmp = __import__(module['name'])
```

...

happy new year :)

============================================================

Hello I need to import dynamically in python script

when I try `__import__()` outside of a function

ex)

```
__import__('myModule')
```

it does work, but when I try it within a function

ex )

```
def func() :
    __import__('myModule')


func()
```

I get an *ImportError*: `ImportError: No module named myModule`

How can I use `__import__()` in function??

Comment: no import()
I wrote __import__()

Comment: Fix your formatting

Comment: You're welcome **:-D :-D**

Comment: Is `func` in a different module from the one where it worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to use here is the following:

```
from importlib import import_module

def func():
    import_module('myModule')
```

Answer (score 0):

When Python starts, [the script’s directory is put at the front of `sys.path`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24435697/8586227), so that `import` finds things in it.  In some cases (not, for example, `python foo/bar.py`), what is put there is an empty string, which means “search the current working directory”.  Only in that case will `os.chdir` affect `import` in the way you expected.