# Python 'from x import y' vs 'from .x import y'

Tags: python, python-import

Can someone explain the difference between these?

1. `from x import y`
2. `from .x import y`

It seems like #1 will import from `x` only if `x` is in `PYTHONPATH` or is in the current working directory, but I don't see any reference of this syntax in the docs https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: You're looking at the docs for the import machinery instead of the import statement. That's like looking at the technical specs for your car's engine when you're trying to find the gas pedal. You want [these docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has multiple ways to find and import modules as detailed in the [Finders and Loaders](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#finders-and-loaders) section of the import documentation. Finders use distribution specific directories, frozen modules, paths in `PYTHONPATH` and usually the directory where the script is loaded. You can get a list of paths in `sys.path` and also`sys.modules.keys()`.

When handling `from x import y` python checks if "x" is already imported, and then goes through the list of finders to see which one pipes up with a solution for a module named "x". Next, it checks whether "x" has a variable called "y". If not, it tries to import a module "y" relative to the "x" it already found.

More details of the syntax and semantics of import can be found in [The import statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) subsection of the Simple Statements section.

The second example only works for modules in packages. The periods tell how far up the package hierarchy to go before descending back down named packages. One dot means current module directory, and each dot moves downwards towards the base.

Comment: Thanks. One other thing that I didn't understand was why `from x import y` works as a substitute for a relative import most of the time, and found the answer is that `PYTHONPATH` automatically gets the current working directory appended when you run a Python script. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435697/python-is-the-current-directory-automatically-included-in-path

Comment: Not quite. Python adds the script's directory to the path, not your current working directory. Your CWD can be anywhere and the import will still work as long as "x" is in your script's directory. Suppose for instance that you put this directory into the system PATH, it would sitll work. And I'm being a bit pedantic, but `PYTHONPATH` is an environment variable that adds to the paths that python will scan. The list of python search paths gets the directory but the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` does not.

Answer (score 0):

These fall under "relative imports" which are located in section 5.7 of the documentation you've linked: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

You can also look at [PEP-382](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports) for the rationale on relative imports and their uses.

Comment: All the examples under 5.7 have a dot prefix, I don't see any answer to my question there