# Python 3: ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'polytest'

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Note:** Answers to similar questions not helping.

First here is the structure of my application:

```
flask-server/
   main.py
   lib/
      __init__.py
      polytest.py
      raw.py
   4-irrelevant-folders/
      ...
```

In my raw.py file, I import the polytest.py file and use it freely (aka no import errors, eveything works). However, in my main.py file I need to import raw.py and do so as such:
`from lib import raw`.

Then upon running the main.py folder, I run into this error:

```
  File "c:\path_to_app\flask-server\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lib import raw
  File "c:\path_to_app\flask-server\lib\raw.py", line 13, in <module>
    import polytest as zone
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polytest'

I'm not sure why I get the ModuleNotFoundError when running main.py, but not when running the raw.py.
Thanks for the help in advance!
```

Comment: It depends how you are running the script, but I think it is likely that `lib` is being added to `PYTHONPATH` when you run `raw.py` by itself.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24435697/3282436) for an explanation.  You probably want that import to be `from . import polytest as zone`.

Comment: This fixed everything! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/*raw.py path*')
import raw
```

Comment: Modifying `sys.path` just to get imports to work is generally a bad idea; it simply masks the underlying problem.  I would only do this if the script was a one-off that I was planning on throwing away soon.

Answer (score 0):

please `try changing your file name from raw to something else`

since may be

it is conflicting with some built in function or module of python

or any file which you have on your system already created.

Comment: Hey the file name is actually something much larger so i just decided to use the first word. Nevertheless thanks for the tip!