# ModuleNotFoundError: Testing package classes with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-import

I understand that there are many resources available and this question is asked many times.
However, I am still wondering why I am getting this error.

I have a project structure like this:

```
PROJECT-MAIN-DIR
    src
        __init__.py
        driver.py
        app
             __init__.py
             app.py
    docs
    tests
        app
            test_app.py
    venv
    .gitignore
    requirements.txt
```

And here is my code:

```
# driver.py
class MyDriverClass:
    pass
```

```
# app.py
from src.driver import MyDriverClass, 

class Application(MyDriverClass):
    def foo():
         print("foo")
```

if I create a file `PROJECT-MAIN-DIR\test_app.py`

```
from src.app.app import Application
def test_app():
    my_app = Application()
    my_app.foo()

test_app()
```

It will work

but if I write a test in `PROJECT-MAIN-DIR\tests\app\unit\test_app.py`

```
from src.app.app import Application
def test_app():
    my_app = Application()
    my_app.foo()
    assert True
```

and run `pytest \tests\app`

Then I have

```
tests\app\unit\test_app.py:1: in <module>
    from src.app.app import Application
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

**How to fix it?**

**Note1**: I am not looking for adding src to path using `sys.path.append`

**Note2**: It is a simplified version of the code and I cannot move things to root. Also I want to keep everything under `src`.

**Note3**: I do want to keep scripts in my package but I need to at least be able to test my classes with pytest

---

**SOLUTION:**
I decided to add this line to `tests\app\unit\test_app.py`

```
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
```

It worked for me

Comment: Your problem primarily is that your main python file shouldn't be the most deeply nested thing in the project. If you don't want to change the search path then anything it needs to import has to be in site packages or in the same folder as it. You said "I understand that there are many resources available and this question is asked many times", did you read and understand those resources and the answers to those questions?

Comment: You should restructure your app, so that the `.py` file you are executing is in the root of your code. Its folder will become the import base.

Comment: It is a simplified version of the code and I cannot move things to root. Also I want to keep everything under `src`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 What if I do not want to have scripts in my package but want to be able to `test classes my package with pytest`?

Comment: The solution is explained in [Can't import my own modules in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383014/cant-import-my-own-modules-in-python) (there are 3 solutions, 2 of them you have rejected, so use the 3rd one)

Comment: The reason is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435697/python-is-the-current-directory-automatically-included-in-path

Comment: question edited