# Importing a local package in python

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python thus the question.

I'm working inside a python package `a`(as in a folder with **init**.py in it), now in my local directory I have a package `b` which has a set of classes(for example say `user.py`).
How do I import `user` into a file inside package `a`.
I tried,

```
import a
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Please create an overview of your folder / file structure and tell us from which working directory you are calling which Python file. Also add all the related import lines from the files.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383014/cant-import-my-own-modules-in-python) might help you