# Python script correctly executes every statement, but also returns ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, module, python-import, importerror, pythoninterpreter

I'm running my Python script in Terminal on MacOS.

The script1.py source code:

```
# A first Python script
import sys              # Load a library module
print(sys.platform)         
print(2 ** 100)             # Raise 2 to a power
x = 'Spam!'
print(x * 8)                # String repetition
```

The output in the Python interactive session:

```
>>> import script1.py
darwin
1267650600228229401496703205376
Spam!Spam!Spam!Spam!Spam!Spam!Spam!Spam!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script1.py'; 'script1' is not a package
```

All the statements in the script are executed correctly, but the interpreter returns an error that says the script can't be found.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import script1.py
```

The interpreter is thinking you're trying to import the module named `py` from inside the package `script1`.

Now, it can find a file called `script1` - that's your file called `script1.py`. So it goes ahead and loads it. And "loading" for python means running the statements inside the file. So it does that. And you get your output.

Then the interpreter realizes that it was expecting `py` to be a module, so `script1` should've been a package (i.e. a directory with source files inside it). But `script1` was just an ordinary file. Hence it throws that error.

When trying to import a module named `script1.py`, you should use:

```
import script1
```

When trying to run a file called `script1.py`, you may use:

```
python script.py
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I don't understand why the interpreter does this. If `import script1.py` marks `script1` as a package and `.py` as its corresponding module, then why not only return an error when the package isn't found? Why is it running `script1` as a module first, then re-reading and identifying it as a package? If I'm understanding correctly, you're saying that the interpreter evaluates this command line twice in two different ways.

Comment: Because the interpreter also looks for the symbol `py` (which may or may not be a module) inside the imported module (`script1` in this case) - if it had found a symbol (like a class or variable) in the `script.py` file, then it would've imported that. Python imports are flexible. BTW a package is nothing but a folder with the `__init__.py` in it and that file is what gets imported (as a module) - so there is no real difference between a package & a module.

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the .py at the end. When you import sys you also dont write `import sys.py`. See also this [post](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383014/cant-import-my-own-modules-in-python) answering how to import your own scripts in python.