# Any way of importing module IN parent folder without using a path insert?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging

Consider the following structure

```
├── __init__.py
├── script.py
├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   ├── utils2.py
```

I know that I can import any function defined in `utils.py` into `script.py` doing `from lib.utils import function`.
Also, I can import any function defined in `utils2.py` into `utils.py` using a relative import, i.e. `from .utils2 import function2`.

With time my root folder has been growing with files so that an additional organization into folders is needed, so I would like to have something like this

```
├── __init__.py
├── realtime
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── script.py
├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   ├── utils2.py
```

If I attempt an import with respect to the package root in `realtime/script.py` now

```
from lib.utils import function
```

I get an error.

Is there any way to resolve the import always with respect to the root folder when I'm running a script inside a subfolder? I would like to avoid having all my main scripts in the root and also avoid having to insert something in `syspath`, which is what many solutions online are suggesting. Does Python not have an official way of dealing with this?

Comment: Never done this myself but [PEP 302](https://peps.python.org/pep-0302/) can be a starting point, e.g. using a [meta hook](https://peps.python.org/pep-0302/#specification-part-2-registering-hooks).

Comment: How do you execute `realtime/script.py`? If your working directory is the root of what you have shown and you run `python realtime/script.py`, the import `from lib.utils import function` should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't import my own modules in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383014/cant-import-my-own-modules-in-python), i.e. create a setup script and install your package so that it will be found in `sys.path`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I do indeed execute `script.py` directly from the `realtime` folder from a bash file. But I just tried to do what you suggested and it still gave me the same error

Comment: Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064426/when-would-the-e-editable-option-be-useful-with-pip-install