# How to import environmental variables from text file in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I have created a txt file of environment variables from one machine using `SET >> textfile` as indicated [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559816/how-to-export-and-import-environment-variables-in-windowse-g-xp)  How can I use that file to import them to a new machine?